# Can I use a different nameserver for a domain that is a nameserver itself as ns1.domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, glue-record

My example.com domain used as the name server for all my other websites and domains, the following name servers have been setup as nameservers on different IP address and servers:

```
ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com
ns3.example.com
ns4.example.com
```

Can I use the following name servers for all my other website but set another 2 nameservers on CloudFlare to route example.com itself.

Right now the nameservers for example.com are the same 4 nameservers, another 100 websites use these nameservers as well. I now want to keep everything the same but use CloudFlare for example.com as name servers. I am wondering if this is a problem and if the root domain of nameservers must point to them as it's authoritative name servers.

Is this safe to do this? Or does it go against any RFC rules?

Comment: I do not understand your first sentence. Do you mean to say: "the following four name servers host all domains for my different websites"?

Comment: @Tommiie Yes, sorry. The 4 nameservers listed are used for many website including their own root domain example.com

Answer (score 0):

There aren't restrictions for it. You can use any domain names for `NS` records of zones.